# Multiplying a vector times the inverse of a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

I have a problem multiplying a vector times the inverse of a matrix in Matlab. The code I am using is the following:

```
% Final Time
T = 0.1;

% Number of grid cells
N=20;
%N=40;
L=20;
% Delta x
dx=1/N

% define cell centers
%x = 0+dx*0.5:dx:1-0.5*dx;
x = linspace(-L/2, L/2, N)';
%define number of time steps
NTime = 100; %NB! Stability conditions-dersom NTime var 50 ville en fått helt feil svar pga lambda>0,5
%NTime = 30;
%NTime = 10;
%NTime = 20;
%NTime = 4*21;
%NTime = 4*19;


% Time step dt
dt = T/NTime

% Define a vector that is useful for handling teh different cells
J  = 1:N;    % number the cells of the domain
J1 = 2:N-1;  % the interior cells 
J2 = 1:N-1;  % numbering of the cell interfaces 

%define vector for initial data
u0 = zeros(1,N);
L = x<0.5;
u0(L)  = 0;
u0(~L) = 1;

plot(x,u0,'-r')
grid on
hold on

% define vector for solution
u = zeros(1,N);
u_old = zeros(1,N);

% useful quantity for the discrete scheme
r = dt/dx^2
mu     = dt/dx;

% calculate the numerical solution u by going through a loop of NTime number
% of time steps
A=zeros(N,N);

alpha(1)=A(1,1);
d(1)=alpha(1);
b(1)=0;                
c(1)=b(1);
gamma(1,2)=A(1,2);

% initial state
u_old = u0;

pause

for j = 2:NTime
A(j,j)=1+2*r;
    A(j,j-1)=-(1/dx^2);
    A(j,j+1)=-(1/dx^2);
u=u_old./A;
    % plotting
    plot(x,u,'-')
    xlabel('X')
    ylabel('P(X)')
    hold on
    grid on
    % update "u_old" before you move forward to the next time level
    u_old = u;

    pause


end

hold off
```

The error message I get is:

```
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in Implicit_new (line 72)
u=u_old./A;
```

My question is therefore how it is possible to perform u=u_old*[A^(-1)] in Matlab?

David

Comment: Do you really want to divide a vector by a matrix? Can you make a small example of a small vector and a matrix and what you expect the result of this division to be?

Comment: You are correct. What I actually want is to multiply vector u with the inverse of A. Is there any easy way to do this in Matlab?(Matrix A is tridiagonal).

Comment: Inverse of matrix A is still a matrix. So if your vector is row vector of size (1,n) and your matrix has size (n,n) then just do `v*A` and you'll get a row vector of size (1,n). As long as inner dimensions are the same, then you can multiply vector by matrix, i.e.  `row_vector*A` is ok  or `A*column_vector` is ok

Comment: Try loosing the dot. `./` is elementwise division, `/` is matrix 'division'(solution). Alternatively use column vectors and `u = A\u_old`.

Answer (score 1):

As knedlsepp said, `v./A` is the elementwise division, which is not what you wanted. You can use either

- `v/A` provided that v is a row vector and its length is equal to the number of columns in A. The result is a row vector.
- `A\v` provided that v is a column vector and its length is equal to the number of rows in A

The results differ only in shape: `v/A` is the transpose of `A'\v'`

Comment: Okay, thank you for your reply. It works, but the problem is then that A is a tridiagonal matrix. Is there a way to divide v by the tridiagonal matrix A without getting NaN as an answer?